# Can I call a System namespace method from LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, import

I want to be able to call the System.Site.getType() method from an LWC JavaScript file.

I thought this would work:

```
import sitegettype from '@salesforce/apex/System.Site.getType';
```

But it gets error, "Unable to find Apex action method". Am I only able to call my own written method marked with @AuraEnabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call your apex method in the lwc with @auraEnabled annotations.

You can create a simple apex class and a method using the site class and then you can call in.

The documentation link is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex)

All the supported lwc modules are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules)